# Docker Hub login with Personal Access Token fails

Tags: docker, command-line-interface, login, token, pat

Windows 11

hub.docker.com

I setup Two-Factor Authentication and generated Personal Access Token (PAT)

Docker Desktop is running.

cmd.exe

```
docker login --username <email for my account>

Password:
```

Typed characters are not visible but I'm sure I'm entering the PAT correctly.

> Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/":
> unauthorized: incorrect username or password

How to further diagnose this issue ?

Comment: IMHO in this kind of authentication you need to provide the password, not PAT

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> docker login --username <email for my account>
> ```

You don't enter your email here, you enter your username. Change the command to:

```
docker login --username <your username>
```